# string Bold on AX 2009 sentence

Tags: axapta

I would like to print the following sentence in BOLD in an AX 2009 report.

```
_ret += element.design().lookupLabel(literalstr("aaa")) + ": " +  strfmt("%1 ", CustPackingSlipTrans.xxx) + "\n";
```

Help me please?

Comment: Are you using MorphX or SSRS reports?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

section.addControl(custTableId, fieldnum(Address, Name)).AOTsetProperties('PROPERTIES\n LeftMargin #10\n Bold #Bold\n FontSize #14\n Top #1\n ENDPROPERTIES\n');

Through this code you are able to set the properties of a Reportsection.

Source:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidferguson/archive/2007/06/01/creating-a-report-in-x-code-and-running.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May be create control in report. Set BOLD in properties of control and display in control.